# Getting array output but I want one output with sparse_categorical loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to fit a simple neural net with keras. I have input and I would like to have a one integer output that represents a class of its own. I want it to be from 0-13 range. However when the last output is set to 1 it gives me an error

```
InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 12 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values:
```

This is what I have so far for compiling the neural net

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(units = 10, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
                     activation = 'relu', input_dim = 10))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 11, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 2000, epochs = 20)
```

My training input are arrays of array and the labels is just an array with values from 0-12

This is the output

[image]

Comment: You have one output unit with sigmoid activation and your y vary 0-13? Because for sigmoid is impossible produce something outside the scale 0-1.

Comment: @viceriel when I change to relu it does provide one output. However it still returns an array of arrays. The first value is the output I want and the rest of the array is just fill with 0.0 till the array is 13 in length. Is there a way to make the neural net predict just the first values in the arrays? or do I have to add extra code to isolate the first values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Lets understand sparse categorical cross-Entropy

it will **just** give you the ability to measure the error via integer labels (instead of one-hot array).

#### so why the error ?

according to what i explained your network should be able to predict 14 classes. so what is done on one-hot coding still needs to be done for the network (not that your feeding one-hot, this was just a flash back to that method to remind us what to do), you need 14 output neurons to do that, therefore;
the last layer should look like this:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 14, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

and by the way its good practice to use `metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy']`

#### if you want integer outputs

there are 2 options (to the best of my knowledge):

```
y_pred = np.argmax(classifier.predict(X_test), axis=1)
```

or simply:

```
y_pred = classifier.predict_classes(X_test)
```

Comment: I'm not one-hot coding my y however. It's categorical whole ints from 0-12. When the last layer is 14 unites it produces an array answer like the one in my question above. However I just want one output between 0-12

Answer (score 1):

If you want integer inputs in the range [0, 13], this corresponds to 14 output classes (indices from 0 to 13, starting from zero), so you need to configure the network appropriately:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 14, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'softmax'))
```

After training, when the model makes a prediction, you will get a probability distribution over integers [0, 13]. To get the encoded integer, you have to take the index with the maximum probability, for example:

```
pred = classifier.predict(some_data)
integer = np.argmax(pred, axis=-1)
```

This will produce the predicted integer label.